# How to read from REDCap forms with data validation into R (REDCapR::readcap_read)

Tags: r, redcap

I've been using the REDCapR package to read in data from my survey form. I was reading in the data with no issue using redcap_read until I realized I needed to add a field restriction to one question on my survey. Initially it was a short answer field asking users how many of something they had, and people were doing expectedly annoying things like spelling out numbers or entering "a few" instead of a number. But all of that data read in fine. I changed the field to be a short answer field (same type as before) that requires the response to be an integer and now the data won't read into R using redcap_read.

When I run:

`redcap_read(redcap_uri=uri, token=api_token)$data`

I get the error message that:

`Column [name of my column] can't be converted from numeric to character`

I also noticed when I looked at the data that that it read in the 1st and 6th records of that column (both zeros) just fine (out of 800+ records), but everything else is NA. Is there an inherent problem with trying to read in data from a text field restricted to an integer or is there another way to do this?

Edit: it also reads the dates fine, which are text fields with a date field restriction. This seems to be very specific to reading in the validated numbers from the text field.

I also tried redcapAPI::exportRecords and it will continue to read in the rest of the dataset, but reads in NA for all values in the column with the test restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade [REDCapR](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/) to the version on GitHub, which stacks the batches on top of each other before determining the data type (see [#257](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/issues/257)).

```r
# install.packages("remotes") # Run this line if the 'remotes' package isn't installed already.
remotes::install_github(repo="OuhscBbmc/REDCapR")
```

In your case, I believe that the batches (of 200 records, by default) contain different different data types (character & numeric, according to the error message), which won't stack on top of each other silently.

The [`REDCapR::redcap_read()`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_read.html) function should work then.  (If not, please create a new [issue](https://github.com/OuhscBbmc/REDCapR/issues)).

Two alternatives are

1. calling  [`redcap_read_oneshot`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_read_oneshot.html) with a large value of `guess_max`, or
2. calling  [`redcap_read_oneshot`](https://ouhscbbmc.github.io/REDCapR/reference/redcap_read_oneshot.html) with `guess_type = TRUE`.